# Kendo UI for JSP- DataSource Servlet or RESTful service

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, telerik-grid

I am new to Kendo UI framework. I would like to know whether I could use normal Servlets or RESTful service instead of Spring Controller for Kendo UI for JSP?

E.g. For the following grid example(http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/index.html), they have used Spring Controller class in data source, so instead of Spring Controller class, could it be possible to use servlets or RESTful service class for datasource?

Any help is highly appreciable.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. This blog post shows how to do it: [Building a better UI – JSP Wrappers part 2](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/13-02-12/building_a_better_ui_ndash_jsp_wrappers_part_2)